# VBA code error - Run time error Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

The first workbook gets populated but the system throws an error when moving on to next workbook. Run time error 13 Type mismatch.

The code I wrote is

```
Sub ProcessWorksheets()
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim permissionDict As Object
    Dim permission As Variant
    Dim usersDict As Object
    Dim user As Variant
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    
    ' Assuming your data starts from row 2 (header in row 1)
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet other than "Sheet1"
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            ' Create dictionaries for each worksheet
            Set permissionDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            
            ' Clear existing data in columns G, H, I, and J
            ws.Range("G:J").ClearContents
            
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            ' Step 2: Populate permissionDict with unique permissions
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
                    permissionDict(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) = ""
                End If
            Next i
            
            ' Step 3: Populate column G with unique permissions
            ws.Cells(1, "G").Value = "Permissions"
            ws.Range("G2").Resize(permissionDict.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(permissionDict.Keys)
            
            ' Loop through unique permissions
            For Each permission In permissionDict.Keys
                If permission <> "" Then ' Check if permission is not empty
                    Set usersDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' Create a new dictionary for each permission
                    
                    ' Step 4: Identify users associated with the permission
                    For i = 2 To lastRow
                        If Not IsError(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) And ws.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
                            If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = permission Then
                                usersDict(ws.Cells(i, "A").Value) = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next i
                    
                    ' Step 5: Populate column H with concatenated users
                    rowIndex = Application.Match(permission, ws.Range("G:G"), 0)
                    If Not IsError(rowIndex) Then
                        ws.Cells(rowIndex, "H").Value = Join(usersDict.Keys, ", ")
                    End If
                    
                    ' Step 6-7: Populate columns I and J
                    For i = 2 To lastRow
                        If Not IsError(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) And ws.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
                            If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = permission Then
                                ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
                                ws.Cells(i, "J").Value = ws.Cells(i, "D").Value
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            Next permission
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA and I am not sure the error I am making.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please specify which line of code is throwing the error.

Comment: Skimming over the code it looks like there is only one Workbook the entire time - you never work with multiple Workbooks, so I don't get what you mean by "throws an error when moving on to next workbook"